# Pagination not displaying desired amount of pages

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am using React to build a small project and I want to implement pagination in my component. I am using a library called `react-pagination-js`. The pagination so far moves through the pages but it does not display the correct amount of posts per page which I have defined as 6? How can I make it work? Currently it displays 30 posts. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Pagination from "react-pagination-js";
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer.jsx';
import CustomHeader from '../CustomHeader/CustomHeader.jsx';
import BlogCategoriesMenu from '../BlogCategoriesMenu/BlogCategoriesMenu.jsx';


const Planets = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(6);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get('https://astroecstatic-express.herokuapp.com/');
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner/>
  }


  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
  const title = 'Articles';

  const retrogradesPosts = posts.filter( (item) => {
            return item.categories === 'retrogrades'
          })

  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) =>{
    if(pageNumber > 0) {
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    }
  } 

  return (
      <div>
            <CustomHeader
               title={title}
              />
              <BlogCategoriesMenu/>
           <div className="planet-articles-container">
          <div className="">
          {retrogradesPosts.map(post => (
          <div key={post._id} className="planet-articles-container__post">
          <img className="planet-articles-container__post-img" src={post.picture} alt="avatar"/>
          <div className="">
           <h2 className="">{post.date}</h2>
            <Link  to={`/post/${post._id}`}> <p className="">{post.title}</p></Link>
           <p className="planet-articles-container__post-text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 100) + "..."}</p>
        </div>
        </div>


          ))}
    </div>
    <Pagination
      currentPage={currentPage}
      showFirstLastPages={true}
      sizePerPage={postsPerPage}
      totalSize={retrogradesPosts.length}
      totalPages={retrogradesPosts.length}
      changeCurrentPage={paginate}
    />
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Planets;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not display the correct amount of posts per page"? What number of posts does it display, then?

Comment: It shows 30 posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are iterating and displaying all the posts in the `retrogradesPosts` object. You should display only the first 6 when the page number is 1 and next 6 for page 2 so on. You can do something like this:

```
const retrogradesPosts = posts.filter( (item) => {
            return item.categories === 'retrogrades'
          })

//get the element number where to start the slice from
const start_from = currentPage * postsPerPage;
//get the element number where to end the slice
const end_on = start_from + postsPerPage;

const postsToDisplay = retrogradesPosts.slice(start_from, end_on)
```

Then map over `postsToDisplay` and render posts instead of `retrogradesPosts`.

```
{postsToDisplay.map(post => (
          <div key={post._id} className="planet-articles-container__post">
          <img className="planet-articles-container__post-img" src={post.picture} alt="avatar"/>
          <div className="">
           <h2 className="">{post.date}</h2>
            <Link  to={`/post/${post._id}`}> <p className="">{post.title}</p></Link>
           <p className="planet-articles-container__post-text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 100) + "..."}</p>
        </div>
        </div>


          ))}
```